# Why date is displayed differently at server and locally?

Tags: c#, date

I am reading data from an API file, which has this format

```
<DataPoint>
<Amount>38.361</Amount>
<Time>2014-01-02T12:00:00</Time>
</DataPoint>
```

when I get the time, and print it at my website at visual studio I get 02/01/2014.
However, If I upload it, I get 1/2/2014.

Why the same code produces different results when I use it at my pc, and when I upload it at the server?

And how I can fix that?

ps: I am programming in C# and I am using the object JArray to get the data if this is important

```
            JArray a = JArray.Parse(text);
```

But it

Answer (score 2):

That's because of the DateTime CULTURE info. British dates are arranged as `dd/MM/yyyy` and American dates are `MM/dd/yyyy` You could just use `Datetime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` to convert it to datetime format you want to display.

Answer (score 2):

Format in which numeric and datetime values are transformed into `string` depends on OS culture settings, when you don't set them explicitly in code. Looks like that's the case here.

If you need the same date/numeric format everywhere, no matter how user set's the OS preferences, you should provide `IFormatProvider` instance which will provide the formatting and override OS default one.

The most commonly used is `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
var dateString = myDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Yes, but isn't it possible to force what date format I want from my c# code?

Comment: Aaa... Thanks a lot. I just saw the update at your post